# Nest thermostat tripping breaker

Tags: thermostat, nest

I have had the nest for about 3 years, it's been working fine. Over the past month the breaker that feeds the nest and the furnace has been tripping although the heat hasn't been used for about 4 months. I replaced the breaker, it tripped  again a day a later, I replaced the breaker a second time, that one tripped within a few hours.
The a/c has been running a lot over the past few weeks but it is on its own breaker and that breaker has not been tripped.
Is this a nest issue, an a/c condenser issue, or something else?
Thank you,

Comment: Does the breaker have a TEST button on it?

Comment: What type of breaker?  If replacement breaker trips also, then there is a problem with the wires that needs to be fixed now.  Replacing breakers usually never fixes the problem.  The breakers are there to prevent fires.

Comment: Typical setup for gas furnace + electric air conditioner is that there will be one breaker for air handler/furnace/thermostat and a separate one for air conditioner. Air conditioner won't run without the air handler. Virtually impossible for a low voltage thermostat to trip a breaker, so that means air handler/furnace. **Model # of furnace/air handler, model # of air conditioner, type of breaker that trips (plain or GFCI or AFCI), picture of breaker panel** will all help.

Answer (score -1):

That would not be a Nest issue.

The breaker that is tripping feeds a 120/24 volt transformer that feeds the Nest and all the relays.

When it trips the Nest should say lost 24 Volt.

I would replace the 24 Volt transformer.

Comment: **Why????** The breaker is the furnace and the Nest. Which most likely means "furnace + air handler and a 24V transformer somewhere". No indication whatsoever that the transformer is the source of the breaker trips.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Simple, the 24 V transformer gets overloaded, hint `The a/c has been running a lot over the past few weeks` means the relays were engaged creating overload on the xformer

Comment: It doesn't work that way. There are people who put the fan on "on" instead of "auto" - so transformer output being used 24/7 - doesn't matter. They're designed to work that way. Something is causing the breaker to **trip**. That might be a GFCI or AFCI issue (which could be related to the transformer, but could be many other things) or an actual true overload. If there is a true overload on the 120V side, the transformer is the least of the problems.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact after reading your comment, what is the OP supposed to do ? Pray ?

Comment: OP should answer the question I already posed of: **Model # of furnace/air handler, model # of air conditioner, type of breaker that trips (plain or GFCI or AFCI), picture of breaker panel** and then we can try to troubleshoot this more methodically.